# How to implement Devise Login with Facebook for Mobile Device

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, mobile, devise

I have to write an API for mobile device to implement Login with Facebook using Devise. I have done the web implementation and the as per my research the Facebook Login flow works as follows:

***Step 1:*** 
The user comes on the website and clicks Login with Facebook. It hits the facebook verifying the permissions for the app.

***Step 2:***
If the user accepts, facebook hits the web application with a temporary code.

***Step 3:***
The web server using the temporary params code hits facebook again to get the user's access token.

***Step 4:***
Facebook hits the web server with the user's access_token which is saved by the web application in the database. If the user with the access_token already exists then a new session is created else a new user record is created.

This is the complete flow of login of Facebook for a web application.

***Now when writing mobile api for a Mobile device the question comes is:***

Will the mobile device hit the web application with the facebook's temporary code as mentioned in Step 2 and the Web server will hit facebook using the temporary code to get the user's permanent access_token?

```
                                  OR
```

Will the mobile devise hit the web server with the permanent user's access_token from facebook which is then identified for its existence in the database by the web application?

Please Help.
Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw [Devise + Facebook OmniAuth integration](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)?

I used this integration and it uses the **step 2**, it's very easy and you don't have to care about this issues, it's already done.